# RecyclerAdapter row is shuffling when scroll quickly

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Hello:) I have seen lot of posts on this subject but I have not solve my problem.

In my application (Android), I have a RecyclerView, with my own Adapter and my own ViewHolder.

And when I scroll quickly the data of each row is shuffling. (Each row contains "x" buttons. And that number of buttons change. And the labels of the buttons change too.)

My Adapter, look like this

```
public class PostRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostRecyclerHolders> {
    private List<Post> posts;
    protected Context context;
    private String userId;
    public PostRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Post> posts,String userId) {
        this.posts = posts;
        this.context = context;
        this.userId = userId;
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }
    @Override
    public PostRecyclerHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        PostRecyclerHolders viewHolder = null;
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_post_row, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new PostRecyclerHolders(layoutView, posts, context);
        return viewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PostsRecyclerHolders holder, int position) {
        Post post = posts.get(position);
        List<But> buts = post.getButs(); //list of But (Contains label and date) max size = 6
        holder.label.setText(post.getLabel());
        //initialize all button
        for(i=0; i<buts.size();i++){
            holder.listButs.get(i).setText(buts.get(i).getLabel());
        }
        //hide other buts
        for(int j = i ;j < 6 ; j++){
            holder.listsButs.get(j).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        holder.userId = userId;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.posts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

And my ViewHolder

```
public class PostRecyclerHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView libelle;
    public LinearLayout butLayout;
    public ArrayList<Button> listButs;
    public String userId;
    public Context context;
    private List<Post> postsObj;

    public PostRecyclerHolders(final View itemView, final List<Post> postsObj, Context context) {
        super(itemView);
        this.context=context;
        this.postsObj = postsObj;
        //list button init
        listButs = new ArrayList<Button>();
        //initialisation des
        libelle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.libelle);
        butLayout= (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.but_list);
        for(int i=0; i<6;i++){
            final int butN = i;
            Button btn = createButton(context, i);
             btnRep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                 /* Do something */
                 }
             });

            listBut.add(btn);
            reponsesLayout.addView(btn);
        }
    }

    //Crate a button
    public Button createButton(Context c, int id){
        Button b = new Button(c);
        b.setText("");
        b.setId(getIdButton(id));
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(0,50,0,0);
        b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        b.setLayoutParams(lp);
        b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_blue);
        b.setClickable(true);
        b.setTextSize(18);
        return b;
    }
}
```

I have set setHasStableIds at true and impletement getItemId, but nothing change. The data is always shuffling.
Someone see where the problem is?

Thank you for your help. (Sorry for my English).

Comment: Why do you generate buttons programatically if you already know how many you need? Why not just declare all of them in the XML?

Comment: I did this because I wanted to generate only a variable numbers of buttons depending of the item. But I did not succeed. But I don't think this is the cause of the problem

Comment: Those for loops inside `onBindViewHolder()`, as well as the one on the `PostRecyclerHolders` constructor and the `setOnClickListener()` work inside it also look very off for my taste.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you can briefly explain why?